# Is the minimal distance of a line to a point always orthongonal to the line

Tags: geometry

I have a point and a (curved) line. Now I want to find the distance to the line where the direction from the point to the point on the line stands orthogonal on the line.
Intuitively I think that the shortest connection between the closest point on the line and the point is always orthogonal, but I'm not 100% sure that my geometry intuition is correct. Can you confirm that for finding the orthogonal connection between a point and a point on a line it is enough to check the closed point on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote can be true, subject to conditions.

1. Your curve must be either closed, or start/end infinitely far away (like the shape of y=1/x or y=x^2). Otherwise, the closest distance can be to an end point of the curve.
2. The curve must be smooth. For instance, a triangle is not smooth, the normal is not defined at the 3 vertices and the closest distance can be a distance to the vertex. Another example, cubic Bézier splines may contain a singularity where the normal is not defined, see the top right picture:
    [image]
   Again, closest distance might be a distance to that singularity point.

Also, don’t forget it can be multiple points on the curve with orthogonal connection. You gonna have to find all of them, and use the minimum distance found. Moreover, in some cases “all of them” can be “infinitely many”, if the curve contains a piece of a circular arc.

Comment: Hey nice answer, yes I thought of 1. as well. I can assume that I'm always between the endpoints of my line. And yes I can assume that my curve is smooth. I anyway want to find only the shortest orthogonal distance, so I just wanted to make sure that I can find this distance by minimizing the euclidean distance